# Implement CiviCrm SAML with Google Suite as IDP provider

Tags: user-account, authentication

I'm helping a small charity in volunteer capacity, most of their work was done on the spreadsheets earlier, they have now started using civicrm for their events and contributions as well as membership, and emails.

They have an intranet built using google suite, and now want to integrate Civicrm with intranet site using SAML authentication for civicrm.

there config is CiviCRM 5.8.2 on drupal 7 - I’ve looked around and tried for extensions for implementing SAML on Civicrm (service provider) using Google as IDP provider, but have not got end to end instructions. Can someone please point me in right direction? I'ld be very thankful and happy to document the step by step instructions and share with all once done.

Answer (score 1):

Civi uses the CMS for authentication so the question is about configuring Drupal 7 (in your case) with Google SAML IDP.

I've not tried it, but a bit of googling shows a few links that look promising:

- Drupal [SAML Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/samlauth) module
- [Set up your own custom SAML application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519)